# template argument of template class

Tags: c++, templates

I have some template class Pool:

```
template<int a>
class Pool{}
```

Now, I have another class where I pass Pool's object pointer as argument:

```
template<int a, Pool<a> &pool>
class Point{}
```

or

```
template<typename PoolT, PoolT &pool>
class Point{}
```

---

Can I somehow avoid first argument? E.g.:

```
template<Pool<?> &pool>
class Point{}
```

Here is example what I am doing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>     /* malloc, free, rand */
using namespace std;

template<int i>
struct Pool{
    int id;
};

struct FE{
    static Pool<1> pool;
};

Pool<1> FE::pool;


template<typename T, T &_p>
struct C{
    int id;
    void* operator new(size_t size){
        std::cout<<"new";
        return malloc(size);
    }

    void test(){
        std::cout << _p.id;
    }
};


int main() {
    FE::pool.id = 120;
    C<Pool<1>, FE::pool> c;
    c.test();
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/1BRUos

Comment: Your syntax is not valid

Comment: *"Can I somehow avoid first argument?"* No, but maybe you can simplify it in the greater scheme of things. A more complete example may help.

Comment: For example, you could just pass a type to `C` and require it to have a static data member named `pool` (or a static member function).

Comment: @DyP - Can you clarify, please?

Comment: `template<typename T> struct C { void test() { cout<<T::pool.id; } }; C<FE> c; c.test();` Whether that's appropriate / a good solution depends on the details. For example, simpler (and probably nicer) solutions are possible if a reference/pointer to `pool` can be stored as a data member.

Comment: Ah no - I will derive from that C. And want not any performance penalty with constructor initializing member pool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial specialization can unpack the argument `1` from the type `Pool`, but there is no way to declare a template that takes a reference to any object and deduces the type. A function can deduce a type given an object, but such an object cannot be used as a non-type template argument.

The best factoring here is probably to make the client type nested within the pool type.

```
template<int i>
struct Pool{
    int id;

    // i and the Pool type are already defined at least within this context.

    template< Pool & p >
    struct C{
        int id;
        void* operator new(size_t size){
            std::cout<<"new";
            return malloc(size);
        }

        void test(){
            std::cout << _p.id;
        }
    };
};

int main() {
    FE::pool.id = 120;
    Pool<1>::C< FE::pool> c;
    c.test();
    return 0;
}
```

The name `Pool<1>::C< FE::pool>` as illustrated still contains the same ugly information, but this factoring is more amenable to a `typedef`, or adding code to the allocator type where relevant information is conveniently in scope.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use a static const member to store the template parameter of Pool?

```
#include <stdio.h>

template<int i>
struct Pool
{
    static const int stored = i;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("%d\n", Pool<5>::stored);
    return 0;
}
```